# getUserMedia is failing with "Permission Denied" in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, webrtc, android-webview, getusermedia

I've been working on a web application which uses WebRTC to perform video calls.
So, before a user start a video call, we invoke [`getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) method to ask the user for permission to use the media devices.

This works just fine in all the major desktop and mobile browsers.
So, we did an experiment by loading our securely deployed web application in the Android WebView. But, surprisingly it never worked.

After debugging we found out that `getUserMedia` is failing with a exception "**Permission Denied**". The prompt to ask for microphone and camera permissions never triggered. It just fails!

So, as described in the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#browser_compatibility) `getUserMedia` has the full support in Android WebView. But I am not sure what's going wrong.

Anyone who has a good idea on what could go wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webview is compatible but the device acces has to be requested from native side in a native app.
The Camera and Microphone [Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring) must be added to the manifest of the app.
Also the webview has to be configured to request that access depending of the webview/app.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre Noyelle! I was a bit confused on the second part of your answer. Apart from calling `getUserMedia`, we also have to call WebView specific method to allow the permissions? Would you have an example code?

Comment: it depend of where your webview is. 
Native webview ? In an app you develop ?  in a tier ?

Comment: Sorry for a late response. We are tying to open the WebView in an Android app. So, it's a native Android WebView. Is that what you were asking?